# Customisable and cross-browser friendly audio player for <audio> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, audio

I'm struggling to find a jQuery sort of player that I could easily customise and apply to my 
website. Basically I am trying to custumize my audio tag:

```
<audio preload="none" controls src="http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/75868018/stream?client_id=7a17129ba9cd5fff34f847e3539829b7">
</audio>
```

as src is from sound-cloud it will always be .mp3 format, therefore I need a player that would fallback in browsers that don't support .mp3 format.

Can anyone suggest such player? Preferably lightweight, easy to install and highly custuizable with css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MediaElement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/) looks like a great bet to me - it appears to be cross-browser, lightweight and easy to implement.

Another few options which may interest you could be [HTML5 Video Player](http://videojs.com/) and [Video for Everybody](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody).