# Play sound button in firefox. It doesnt work but should

Tags: firefox, audio, playback, wav

I found a source code online that works in firefox.
http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/mark/audio/play10.htm

Go open that link in firefox and click the play button. I tried following the instructions but it did not work so well. The bar disappeared after 1 second and the button didn't trigger anything. It also didn't work in ie. HELP! I've searched very long and this is the closest i got to finding a working piece without flash

BTW, I am using .wav

Answer (score 0):

I guess noone would rewrite the above sample to get it working..

You should choose a better sample..

Refer to :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17789204/create-cross-browser-audio-player-that-look-same

[Customisable and cross-browser friendly audio player for <audio> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15838257/customisable-and-cross-browser-friendly-audio-player-for-audio-tag)

[Backwards and cross-browser compatible audio playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16282208/backwards-and-cross-browser-compatible-audio-playing)